# How to decrease a memory in paged pool that consumed by CM31 tag?

Tags: windows, memory, memory-leaks

My RAM disappears for unknown tasks. I have known that my Paged pool has grown to 582 MB. Task manager does not show which process has consumed this RAM. Poolmon: CM31 = 338 MB, MmSt = 42, CM25 = 33, MmRe = 19...

This information is collected while Opera browser and Thunderbird work. Closed apps before monitoring: Element Desktop, Nheko.

In fact I did not capture when Paged pool has started to grow. I monitored 36 hours Paged pool is about 580 MB all time. I want to decrease memory consuming by CM31, but I don't like idea to reboot my PC each time. How can I decrease Paged pool without system reboot?

Findstr returned empty result for system32. I also tried to find driver using findstr in syswow64. Empty result else.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: That doesn't seem high and you say it hasn't increased for 36 hours. It doesn't sound like you have a driver with a leak. To identify a driver from a tag, you can use the rather crude command line, e.g.: `findstr /m /l CM31 C:\windows\system32\DRIVERS\*.sys` but it seems ok from your description. One way to troubleshoot a pool leak that can visually seen to be happening is to run: `wpr.exe -start Pool`, leave it for say up to 5 mins, then run: `wpr.exe -stop C:\pool.etl`.  Using Windows Performance Analyzer you can see all the allocations by tag during this windows and their stacks.

Comment: @HelpingHand yes, it is not increasing, but I suppose it's because I has stopped to do something to grow. Thank you for command, it found nothing for CM31, MmSt, CM25. But it works - results for MmRE.

Comment: Driver Sys files don't have to be stored under `C:\windows\system32\DRIVERS` but they typically are. One way to check is to run `msinfo32`.  From there you can expand `Software environment` -> `System drivers` to view all the drivers, loaded or not.  This will give you all the paths.  Maybe there are drivers outside of the above directory you can run findstr against to search for the tags.